# if statement with multiple condition not working...

Tags: c++

here is my code :

```
string function1( string input)
{
    string output;
    int i=0;
    if (input.at(i)!='A' || input.at(i)!='a'|| input.at(i)!='E' || input.at(i)!='e' || input.at(i)!='I' || input.at(i)!='i' || input.at(i)!='O'||input.at(i)!='o' || input.at(i)!='U' || input.at(i)!='u')
    {
            char x=input[i];
            input.erase(input.begin()+i);
            output=input+x;
    }
    else
    {
        output=input+"yay";

    }

    return output;
}
```

- but its not doing what i want it to do.. can't figure out where its going wrong...

can any1 help?

Basically the issue is that its never going in to the else statement..

if i pass in BJ it should return BJYAY right..
but its giving me JB

Thanks!

Comment: Read it aloud to yourself.

Comment: I think you want `&&`, not `||`. Think about the logic of what the condition is.

Comment: `input.at(i)!='A' || input.at(i)!='a'` is always true in my universe.

Comment: i meant.. if i pass in is it should return isyay right?, but its returning si

Comment: Whenever proof reading my own code, I STILL sometimes get this wrong.  Hence, I've learned to apply DeMorgan's law as an alternative "proof reading" exercise.  In this case I would apply DeMorgan's law and state that I would execute the ELSE clause when (reading aloud, to myself) "input at i equals 'A', AND input at i equals 'a', AND input at i equals 'B', er, whoa, that's not right!".  Usually by the first few conditions you've figured out that the original condition is not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `||` operators of the `if` statement to `&&`.  The statement you have written is always true.  What you want is that the first character is not a vowel, i.e. it does not match 'A' AND it does not match 'E', etc.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the != to == will give you the result requested.

Comment: no, it won't.  the character can't be equal to more than one value.

Comment: Thanks.. but I realize I was asking a silly question above... lol.. Once i read it out loud it made sense why i wasn't getting the answer i needed...